# Android Chronometer: set format of chronometer

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a chronometer format (**hh:mm:ss**). I like to have a format (**mm:ss**) (Minutes only).

for example: 01:30:00 to 90:00. Please help me

Comment: I haven't use setFormat(). Just a default format of chronometer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
/**
 * Format of the time
 */
private final static String MINUTE_SECOND_FORMAT = "%02d:%02d";

///// code... 

final int minutes = (currentSeconds % 3600) / 60;
final int seconds = currentSeconds % 60;

String formatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), MINUTE_SECOND_FORMAT, minutes, seconds);
```

With this you get a formatted string in minutes:second format.